# different custom view engine per request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I'm working with NopCommerce 3.8 and ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have a number of domains pointed at the same web site. 
I want to serve up a different "virtual" site depending on the domain, by registering

1. a different set of registered autofaq dependencies
2. a different set of mapped routes
3. a different custom view engine

..depending on the requested domain. Basically a given plugin will "apply itself" if and only if the requested domain matches a particular pattern.

In my DependencyRegistrar and in my RouteProvder, I've set up an "OnBeginRequest" function, which gets registered with a custom event manager, so that those methods are called later when a particular event is raised, and then I raise that event in the Global.asax.

But the static data structures I'm registering event handlers into seem to be getting discarded by the time Application_BeginRequest runs; I guess it's a different request, and. It seems that you can't rely on things that are placed in static structures necessarily hanging around between requests.

Is there some fundamental reason why what I'm trying to do can't or shouldn't be done?

Do I really need to have a whole separate copy of the NopCommerce code base for each different site? What I want is to just have a different plugin per site.